# Angular2 npm start: What are access URLs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, npm

Whenever I run `npm start` in my angular 2 project directory, I see following lines in console response:

```
  Access URLs:
  ------------------------------------
        Local: http://localhost:3000
     External: http://10.28.93.96:3000
  ------------------------------------
           UI: http://localhost:3001
  UI External: http://10.28.93.96:3001
  ------------------------------------
```

What is the difference between Local and External here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per as my understanding, in your local machine you can use both url. But if you want to test in in different machine(like iPad, mobile or other desktop application) Then you have to use:

```
UI External: http://10.28.93.96:3001
```

Only. But if is there any firewall then you cannot use this. So try in your same network Or change network settings.